# Python: Write a JSON file with unknown number of keys to a csv file?

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary, nested

I have a JSON file which contains lines like below:

```
{"target":"http://103.15.234.121","http_status":302,"plugins":{"Country":{"string":["SINGAPORE"],"module":["SG"]},"Apache":{},"X-Powered-By":{"string":["PHP/5.5.24"]},"IP":{"string":["103.15.234.121"]},"PHP":{"version":["5.5.24"]},"RedirectLocation":{"s
    tring":["http://www.greenplanthydro.com.hk/"]},"HTTPServer":{"string":["Apache"]}}}
    {"target":"http://101.0.99.93","http_status":301,"plugins":{"Country":{"string":["AUSTRALIA"],"module":["AU"]},"Apache":{},"IP":{"string":["101.0.99.93"]},"Title":{"string":["301 Moved Permanently"]},"RedirectLocation":{"string":["http://www.101.0.99.93
    /403.shtml"]},"HTTPServer":{"string":["Apache"]}}}
```

I have already tried to load JSON object line by line but I am not sure how to convert it to csv with keys as headers , mainly because I do not know the number of keys:

```
data_dict = []
file = open('../input_file','r')
for line in file:
    data_dict.append(json.loads(line))
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Your JSON in the file does not seem to be a valid JSON.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid and CSV represents a row structure while json represents a "tree". You need to decide how to flatten your structure. Once this is done, it's trivial to actually dump in into a csv.

Comment: @Bruce Thanks did not notice that. do you know any method to flatten the invalid Json structure?